# Windows Functions and Group By

Tags: sql, window-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to run this query and I get the SQL compilation error: [CAST(OV.TOTAL_VALUE AS NUMBER(25,5))] is not a valid group by expression

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', CREATED_AT) as WEEK, SUB_GROUP, AVG(TOTAL_VALUE) as AOV_VERTICAL, AVG(TOTAL_VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('week', CREATED_AT))
FROM OV
GROUP BY 1,2
```

I have a table containing a date, a subgroup and a total value and I would like a table with the average total value by week and sub_group and a second column with the average by week.

I'm using snowflake.

Thanks!

Comment: Some sample data and desired results would clarify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the overall average, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', CREATED_AT) as WEEK, SUB_GROUP,
       AVG(TOTAL_VALUE) as AOV_VERTICAL,
       SUM(SUM(TOTAL_VALUE)) / SUM(COUNT(*)) as overall_avg
FROM OV
GROUP BY 1,2
```